# Segfault while using transactional memory, tried to implement golang's chan analog

Tags: c++

My code is following,logic is readable,i'm not sure about atomic's,it's compile without even warning's,but i get segfault's again and again

```
#include <atomic>
//#include <mutex>
#include <memory>
//#include <math.h>
//#include <optional>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

namespace tema2 {
template <class T,size_t A>
class fl_chan {
public:
    fl_chan(){
        //long unsigned int zero = 0;
        place_st.store(0);
        take_st.store(0);
        delta.store(0);
        return;
    };
    bool recv(T &trg){
        synchronized {
            synchronized {
                if (take_st == A){
                    take_st.store(0);
                }
            }
            if (delta == 0){
                return false;
            }

            T var = T();
            swap(var,data[take_st++]);
            trg = var;
            --delta;
            return true;
        }
    }
    bool send(T arg){
        synchronized {
            synchronized {
                if (place_st == A){
                    place_st.store(0);
                }
            }
            data[place_st++]=arg;
            ++delta;
            return true;
        }
    }

private:
    T data[A];
    atomic<uint64_t> place_st;
    atomic<uint64_t> take_st;
    atomic<uint64_t> delta;
};


};
```

Comment: Might be time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At the very least, please learn how to use a debugger to catch crashes when they happen, and how to locate where in your code it happens.

Comment: The vast majority of the programs that compile without warnings or errors are wrong in at least one way.

Comment: There are several possible ways I can see that this can go wrong, but without a [mcve] that shows how `f1_chan` is used we can only guess.